# antlr4 parser re-use and warm up

Tags: antlr4

In my use case I have to parse several thousand small and independent expressions into a tree representation using a Visitor on the generated parse trees.
Currently new streams, lexer and parser instances are created for each parse operation.

I assume this might not be optimal. Which object instances could be re-used in such a setup to make use of the warm-up property of ANTLR4? How about thread safety - which of these instances should be thread local? Is a reset of some kind required to re-use a lexer or parser instance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the early days of ANTLR 4 (many months before its initial release), the adaptive DFA cache was created on a per-instance basis, so the use of `Lexer.setInputStream` or `Parser.setInputStream` was essential for achieving good performance.

This is no longer the case. The background cache is now shared among all parser instances and is thread safe. The methods of the `Lexer` and `Parser` classes are not thread safe, so if you want to parse on multiple threads, you will need to create multiple instances of your lexer and parser.

Comment: Does this include all the runtimes and targets as well?